# What is $\mathbb{Q}[x,y,z]$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The ring $R$ is defined as $\mathbb{Q}[x,y,z]$ and a linear map $\phi : R^3 \rightarrow R^2$ is defined by the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}
    x       & y & z  \\
    y       & x & z 
\end{bmatrix}$$

> My question concerns the notation. What does an element from $R$ and $R^3$ look like?

Comment: it seems that it is a ring of polynomials with three variables (not sure).

Comment: And usually $R^3=\{(a,b,c):\ a,b,c\in R\}$.

Answer (score 2):

$R=\mathbb Q[x,y,z]$ is the ring of polynomial expressions in the three variables $x$, $y$ and $z$, with rational coefficients.

A typical element of $R$ could be
$$ x^2+\tfrac{222}{217}y^2z^{16}+z-42 \qquad\in R$$

An element of $R^2$ is just three such polynomials taken together in a triple:
$$ v = \left< x^2+\tfrac{222}{217}y^2z^{16}+z-42, 0, 1-\tfrac{222}{217}xy^2z^{15} \right> \qquad\in R^2$$

The image of this element under your $\phi$ is
$$ \begin{align} \langle\, & x(x^2+\tfrac{222}{217}y^2z^{16}+z-42)+y\cdot0+z(1-\tfrac{222}{217}xy^2z^{15}), \\
& y(x^2+\tfrac{222}{217}y^2z^{16}+z-42)+z\cdot0+z(1-\tfrac{222}{217}xy^2z^{15}) \,\rangle\end{align}
$$
which equals
$$\begin{align} \langle\, & x^3+xz-42x+z, \\
& x^2y+\tfrac{222}{217}y^3z^{16}+yz-42y+z-\tfrac{222}{217}xy^2z^{16} \,\rangle\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks that is what I suspected! So a simple example would be $[2x,y,z] \in R^3$ implies that $$\begin{bmatrix}
    x       & y & z  \\
    y       & x & z 
\end{bmatrix} [2x,y,z]^T = \begin{bmatrix} 2x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \\ 2xy + xy + z^2 \end{bmatrix}$$ ?

Comment: @articuno: Yes, except you would write the second component of the result as $3xy+z^2$ instead.